# How to manage multiple ScrollView widgets using one useScrollController() hook?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-hooks

Flutter documentation for [ScrollController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) has this paragraph:

> Scroll controllers are typically stored as member variables in State objects and are reused in each State.build. A single scroll controller can be used to control multiple scrollable widgets, but some operations, such as reading the scroll offset, require the controller to be used with a single scrollable widget.

Does this mean that we cannot pass the same `ScrollController` to different `ScrollView` widgets to read `ScrollController.offset`?

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

1. There are two screens. Each screen has a `ListView.builder()` widget.
2. Through parameters I pass from screen 1 to screen 2 an object `ScrollController` and apply it to `ListView`.
3. I use scrolling and the `offset` value changes, but as soon as I move/return to another screen, the `offset` is knocked down to 0.0 and I see the beginning of the list.
4. The same `ScrollController` object is used all the time (hashcode is the same)

How can we use one `ScrollController` object for different `ScrollView` widgets, so that the `offset` is not knocked down when moving from screen to screen?

This problem can be solved a bit if, when switching to another screen, we create a new `ScrollController` object with `initialScrollOffset = oldScrollController.offset` and pass it to `ScrollView`.

**Update**:
I don't seem to understand how to use [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks). I created a simple example showing that if we use separate widgets and specify `ScrollController` as a parameter, the scroll is reset to position 0.0.

Reference for an example:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=d31f4714ce95869716c18b911fee80c1

How do we overcome this?

Comment: And even if we still simplify the example and use `StatefulWidget` instead of hooks, where we store `ScrollController` and pass it to other widgets, it still won't work( So it's my misunderstanding of the basic mechanics of `ScrollController`... What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the best solution I can offer is to pass `final ValueNotifier<double> offsetState;` instead of `final ScrollController controller;` as a widget parameter.

Then, in each widget we create a `ScrollController`. By listening to it via the `useListenableSelector` hook we change the `offsetState`.

To avoid unnecessary rebuilding, we use the `useValueNotifier` hook.

A complete example looks like this:

```dart
void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MyApp(),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends HookWidget {
  const MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('#build $MyApp');

    final isPrimaries = useState(true);

    final offsetState = useValueNotifier(0.0);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(isPrimaries.value
            ? 'Colors.primaries List'
            : 'Colors.accents List'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => isPrimaries.value = !isPrimaries.value,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit_sharp),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: isPrimaries.value
          ? ListPrimaries(offsetState: offsetState)
          : ListAccents(offsetState: offsetState),
    );
  }
}

class ListAccents extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const ListAccents({
    Key? key,
    required this.offsetState,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ValueNotifier<double> offsetState;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('#build $ListAccents');

    final controller =
        useScrollController(initialScrollOffset: offsetState.value);

    useListenableSelector(controller, () {
      print(controller.positions);
      if (controller.hasClients) {
        offsetState.value = controller.offset;
      }
      return null;
    });

    return ListView(
      primary: false,
      controller: controller,
      children: Colors.accents
          .map((color) => Container(color: color, height: 100))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

class ListPrimaries extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const ListPrimaries({
    Key? key,
    required this.offsetState,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ValueNotifier<double> offsetState;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('#build $ListPrimaries');

    final controller =
        useScrollController(initialScrollOffset: offsetState.value);

    useListenableSelector(controller, () {
      print(controller.positions);
      if (controller.hasClients) {
        offsetState.value = controller.offset;
      }
      return null;
    });

    return ListView(
      primary: false,
      controller: controller,
      children: Colors.primaries
          .map((color) => Container(color: color, height: 100))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Another idea was to use `useEffect` hook and give it a function to save the last value at the moment of `dispose()`:

```dart
useEffect(() {
  return () {
    offsetState.value = controller.offset;
  };
}, const []);
```

But the problem is that at this point, we no longer have clients.

---

**Bonus:**

If our task is to synchronize the scroll of the `ListView`, another `useListenableSelector` hook added to each of the widgets solves this problem. *Remind* that we cannot use the same `ScrollController' for two or more lists at the same time.

```dart
useListenableSelector(offsetState, () {
  if (controller.hasClients) {
    // if the contents of the ListView are of different lengths, then do nothing
    if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent < offsetState.value) {
      return;
    }
    controller.jumpTo(offsetState.value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve.

But if you are trying to maintain the scroll offset of each scrollable widget after changing tabs then you can use this:

```dart
// This can be any scrollable widget 
ListView(
  controller: _scrollController,
  // This allows to maintain the scroll position of the list
  key: PageStorageKey<String>(<unique_name>), // the unique name can be the name of the tab for example
  children[...],
),
```

If instead, you are trying to match the scroll offset of both tabs even by scrolling in one of them you can use the `TrackingScrollController()` instead of a regular `ScrollController()`. This will match the initial offset of both lists when changing tabs so it always matches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The `PageStorageKey` helps to keep the position for the two lists. And if we pass such a key to different lists, then when we go to the second screen our position will be saved. Probably what I ended up looking for is `TrackingScrollController()`. I didn't even know it existed :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help. Could you please mark my response as the valid response. Thanks in advance & happy coding!